# Nested XML has special characters instead of tags

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a xml type column in postgresql table. I am trying to create a new xml using some of the columns of tables which includes XML type column also.

I am getting special characters like `&quot; &gt; &#xA;    &lt;` etc for internal XML.

How can I get actual tags and symbols instead of these characters?

Below is the Internal XML Sample

```
<Detail>
    <RuleDetail Name="Test">
      <If>
        <Conditions>
          <Condition ConditionID="E4A073ED-A572-4CC5-AC68-835445C0DB6F"/>
        </Conditions>
        <Actions>
          <Action ActionID="A959CF33-3537-486A-B6BB-2DBDFD7B32B9"/>
        </Actions>
      </If>
    </RuleDetail>
</Detail>
```

Below is outer XML Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rules>
   <Rule RuleID="6df3b89e-ef0f-4016-936c-0138d80b0c4e" Name="TODO: test1" SectionID="c8030a47-aa34-4d51-84ff-dcfe11e05599" Detail="&lt;Detail&gt;&#xA;    &lt;RuleDetail Name=&quot;Test&quot;&gt;&#xA;      &lt;If&gt;&#xA;        &lt;Conditions&gt;&#xA;          &lt;Condition ConditionID=&quot;E4A073ED-A572-4CC5-AC68-835445C0DB6F&quot;/&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/Conditions&gt;&#xA;        &lt;Actions&gt;&#xA;          &lt;Action ActionID=&quot;A959CF33-3537-486A-B6BB-2DBDFD7B32B9&quot;/&gt;&#xA;          &lt;/Actions&gt;&#xA;      &lt;/If&gt;&#xA;    &lt;/RuleDetail&gt;&#xA;  &lt;/Detail&gt;" AddedDate="2019-03-07T13:46:13.543" DeleteFlag="false" />
</Rules>
```

Below is the query which i am using

```
Select   XMLELEMENT(name "Rules",XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(name "Rule", XMLATTRIBUTES(RuleID as "RuleID", Name as "Name", SectionID as "SectionID", Detail as "Detail", AddedDate as "AddedDate", ModifiedDate as "ModifiedDate", DeleteFlag as "DeleteFlag"))))
From RuleDetail
```

Detail Columns is XML Type

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete query you are using

Comment: I don't understand the question. The query runs on a table called `ruledetail` and will not produce and HTML escapes. There must be something more that you forgot to tell us. What is the meaning of your "XML sample"?

Comment: Internal XML Sample means actual internal XML. But while creating bigger XML this internal XML gets encoded. I don't want it to be encoded.